# При смене языка в приложении загружать соответствующую таблицу из БД

Tags: java, android, sqlite, locale

В приложении имеется `values/en`, `values/ru` и `values/tr` при смене языка в системе андроид на один из трех упомянутых меняется язык и в приложении. Но у меня есть база данных в приложении, каким образом нужно правильно реализовать, чтобы при смене языка срабатывала определенная таблица? Например когда `values/ru` чтобы загружались данные из таблицы `TABLE_RU`? Или это делается как-то иначе?

Comment: Записать имена таблиц в стринг-ресурс как и обычные строки. и `getString(R.string.table_name)` автоматически вернёт нужную локаль

Comment: Выведите пожалуйста в ответ, отмечу как правильный ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно записать имена таблиц в стринг-ресурс как и обычные строки.
И метод `getString(R.string.table_name)` автоматически вернёт имя соответствующее нужной локали

Comment: А если необходимо сохранять данные, полученные, скажем, из интернета? Просто автор говорит по базы данных, а это не то же самое, что и ресурсы